# How do I set my current Github backup email to be my primary email, and vice versa?

Tags: github

Is it possible to swap my current primary and backup emails on Github? My primary email is currently a student account which I will lose access to in a few years. Looking at Github's documentation it seems that to select a new primary email you first have to add a new address, however the email that I would like to set as my primary address is already added (as the backup email).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you can do is, in the field for "backup email" you can switch your account from the current back-up account to "Allow all verified emails" and then `Save`. That will allow you to change your primary account from the drop-down menu to whichever account you want and again `Save`. Once done, you can again choose your new backup account from the drop-down menu and `Save`.

Quite some manual steps you need to go through for a simple transpose of emails... Not sure why they did it like that (although with all of the saves and what-not it makes some sense).